# Получение текста из тега без класса

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется такой код. Мне нужно получить второй span, который без класса, нужно это для парсинга страницы. Помогите

Comment: `soup.find('span', class_='hidden', text='Цена:').find_next('span').get_text()` Ввиду неполноценного вопроса, не вижу смысла писать полноценный ответ.

Comment: @Namerek 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведенном Вами примере нижеприведенный код будет работать:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html = """
<div class="price">
    <span class="hidden">Цена:</span>
    <span>349 890 T</span>
</div>
"""

soup = Soup(html, 'html.parser')

print(
    soup.find(
        'div', class_='price'
    ).find_next(
        'span',
        class_=[]
    ).get_text(strip=True)
)

print(
    soup.find(
        'span', 
        class_='hidden', 
        text='Цена:'
    ).find_next(
        'span'
    ).get_text()
)
# 349 890 T
# 349 890 T
```

> Если желаете получить ответ применимый к другим исходникам, приведите другой пример исходников или дайте ссылку на ресурс откуда пытаетесь парсить данные

```py
# Будет работать даже так
print(
    soup.find(
        'div', class_='price'
    ).find_next(
        'span',
        class_=False
    ).get_text(strip=True)
)
```